# React site not naturally indexing

Tags: reactjs, seo, search-engine

As "a pet" project I created a website in React (my first...). Google wasn't indexing from itself so I forced 5 main pages to be indexed from search-console. One of these pages is https://contentseekers.com/brands/ with about 50 links to subpages. The main-page is now indexed for a couple of months BUT NONE of the subpages are indexed in Google. I've never experienced this and have no clue why Google is not indexing naturally...Lighthouse scores (SEO) are very good but and zero search-console issues...none of the subpages are indexed...I know I can force the subpages with a sitemap.xml but I would like to know why they are not naturally indexed...

Comment: Google's crawler doesn't use JavaScript. React routing doesn't work without JavaScript. That's why devs move to server-side rendering to mitigate this issue

Comment: Hi Konrad,
Thanks for the answer, I was thinking the Google bot recognises JS these days but apparently not....